# Child / Item added listener gridview android?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to create an onChildAdded or onItemAdded listener to a GridView in android? I can't seem to find one online. Right now my approach is lacking, I feel that it should be improved. I have a worker thread running that remembers the number of children that the GridView has, then if it has more it calls a method that handles the event and if there are less then it calls another method. I'm sure there has to be a better way, but I don't know of one.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own Adapter, extending BaseAdapter. [Check this out.](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)